# Adding a new column based existing multiple columns created a column of list unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame called df, and would like to add a column "profit" based on the existing columns.

Using this logic:

```
If decision == "buy":
    profit = 100/df["open"] * (df["close"] - df["open"])
If decision == "sell": 
    profit = 100/df["open"] * (df["open"] - df["close"])
If decision == "hold": 
    profit = 100/df["open"] * (df["open"] + df["close"])
```

Code:

```
value = [[110, 95, 10, "buy"], [92, 90, -3.2, "sell"], [88, 85, -2.2, "sell"],
         [90, 95, 5.9, "hold"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(value, columns=['open', 'close', 'return', 'decision'])

df["profit"] = [(100 / df["open"] * (df["close"] - df["open"])) if x == "buy"
                else (100 / df["open"] * (df["open"] - df["close"])) for x in
                df["decision"]]
```

The result created a list value for each value in profit column, that not what I expected. I want the profit column created as: `[-13.63, 2.17, 3.41, 5.55]`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html#numpy-select):

```
conditions = [df['decision'].eq('buy'),
              df['decision'].eq('sell'),
              df['decision'].eq('hold')]
values = [100 / df["open"] * (df["close"] - df["open"]),
          100 / df["open"] * (df["open"] - df["close"]),
          100 / df["open"] * (df["close"] + df["open"])]

df['profit'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

`df`:

```
   open  close  return decision      profit
0   110     95    10.0      buy  -13.636364
1    92     90    -3.2     sell    2.173913
2    88     85    -2.2     sell    3.409091
3    90     95     5.9     hold  205.555556
```

---

Imports and DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

value = [[110, 95, 10, "buy"], [92, 90, -3.2, "sell"], [88, 85, -2.2, "sell"],
         [90, 95, 5.9, "hold"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(value, columns=['open', 'close', 'return', 'decision'])
```

---

Why didn't the original work?

Because mathematical operations on Series behave as follows:

```
100 / df["open"] * (df["close"] - df["open"])
```

```
0   -13.636364
1    -2.173913
2    -3.409091
3     5.555556
dtype: float64
```

So the list comprehension creates a list of Series based on where `decision` is `buy`:

```
[(100 / df["open"] * (df["close"] - df["open"]))
 if x == "buy" else
 (100 / df["open"] * (df["open"] - df["close"]))
 for x in df["decision"]]
```

```
[0   -13.636364   <- Buy Calculation
1    -2.173913
2    -3.409091
3     5.555556
dtype: float64, 
0    13.636364   <- Sell Calculation
1     2.173913
2     3.409091
3    -5.555556
dtype: float64, 
0    13.636364   <- Sell Calculation
1     2.173913
2     3.409091
3    -5.555556
dtype: float64, 
0    13.636364   <- Sell (Not Buy) Calculation
1     2.173913
2     3.409091
3    -5.555556
dtype: float64]
```

Comment: Let's if I have another option "hold", can I use np.where?

Comment: What do you want the value to be for "hold"?

Comment: Let's say 100/df["open"] * (df["close"] + df["open"]). I added an "hold" value.

Comment: `np.select` is better for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  np.select it the best choice.